# Do the playstore updates work if the app is installed with a different account?

Tags: google-play, account

Do the updates work if the app is installed with a different account but is currently logged in with own account?

I would like to deliver the Android devices with my pre-installed app and the devices will receive updates later if the customer logs on with his own account.

Answer (score 0):

They will work, but this kind of installation is not recommended and could be consider a security risk and Google may notice that one account has logged on numerous devices and block the account.

it is better to install the app via APK file without logging on with any account. you can get an exact Google Play APK from Google Play console.

Comment: do the updates work when the app is installed for the first time via APK?

Comment: Maybe the first update after changing accounts should be manual but after that it will update automatically